# Observers frame of reference for history / chronolgy of very early universe

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, cosmological-inflation

What is the observers frame of reference when discussing t=0 the instant of the big bang, or the Plank epoch, or the Grand Unification Epoch, or the Inflation, or the Electroweak Epoch?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The age of the universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/104153/)

Comment: @Ben Crowell; My confusion is that this answer states frame of reference that is co-moving with the galaxies, and the subject of interest is prior to existence of galaxies. Perhaps it makes no sense to ask the modified question, "What would be the observers frame of reference before recombination, CMB, star formation, galaxy formation...?"